# Good OAuth gems for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I'm trying to create an application that uses a lot of different OAuth clients, like Facebook, Google, Microsoft Azure, Outlook, Pocket, Windows Live, and Yahoo. I don't want to manually create strategies for each of these providers. Is there some sort of gem which will allow me to easily create or use strategies for OAuth providers like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) is a great choice and I think works perfectly for what you're trying to do. It has a very large preexisting library of OAuth strategies (I think most of the providers you listed are covered). It makes using API keys and redirect URI's that are custom to the development environment very easy, since it can store these credentials in a standalone file.